# What's the scope of table aliases?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM tableA as t1 inner join tableB as t2 on t1.id=t2.some_id) as t3,
     (SELECT * FROM tableC as t1 inner join tableD as t2 on t1.id=t2.some_id) as t4
WHERE t3.id=t4.id
```

Will the two `t1`s and `t2`s clash?

In my experience with multiple database vendors they won't clash, but, could it confuse the optimizer to the point of producing a buggy result in SQLite or SQLs in general?

I have this hypothesis for a query giving bogus results in SQLite.

Comment: Optimizers seldom get confused, coders don't know the language definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the aliases will not clash.  They are known only in their respective subqueries.

In general, you should avoid commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.