# Trouble Aliasing tables when using subqueries and INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join, alias

I'm trying to print the ID and name from a distinct station along with the total number of rides from that station.

The ID and name come from the `stations` table, while the number of trips comes from the `trips` table, so I created a query of the form:

```
SELECT id, name and num_rides
FROM (SELECT COUNT (*) num_rides
    FROM tableB AS b) AS num_rides
INNER JOIN tableA AS a ON  a.station_id = b.start_station_id
```

The problem is the JOIN statement of the outer query doesn't recognize the `b` alias for my table, which I aliased in the inner query.

I tried running the queries separately, and they both work fine.

Why doesn't the computer remember my inner query alias on the outer query?

Error: `Unrecognized name: trips`, trips being the alias I used for table B.

```
SELECT 
    station_id,
    name,
    num_of_rides AS num_of_rides_starting_at
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        start_station_id,
        COUNT(*) number_of_rides
    FROM
        bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips AS trips
    GROUP BY
        trips.start_station_id
    )
    AS num_of_rides
INNER JOIN
    bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations AS stations
ON stations.station_id = trips.start_station_id
ORDER BY num_of_rides DESC
```

Comment: There's no reason for it to 'recognize the "b" alias for my table, which I aliased in the inner query'. What is your justification (referencing authoritative documenation) for expecting it? [mre]

Comment: Query scoping isn't top to bottom, it is outside in with SELECT last.

Comment: [What's the scope of table aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68026259/3404097)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the scope of table aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026259/whats-the-scope-of-table-aliases)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the "trips" alias is only active inside the parentheses. Try naming that whole select statement and referencing that name.

```
SELECT 
   station_id,
   name,
   num_of_rides AS num_of_rides_starting_at
FROM
   (
       SELECT
           start_station_id,
           COUNT(*) number_of_rides
       FROM
           bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips AS trips
       GROUP BY
           trips.start_station_id
   ) NeedNameHere
   AS num_of_rides
INNER JOIN
bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations AS stations 
   ON stations.station_id = NeedNameHere.start_station_id
ORDER BY num_of_rides DESC
```

Comment: Name is not included in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    station_id, /*from table: citibike_stations */
    name, /*from table: citibike_trips */
    number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station /*from table: station_num_trips*/
FROM
   (SELECT  
        start_station_id,
        COUNT(*) number_of_rides
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
    GROUP BY start_station_id
   )
   AS station_num_trips
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` 
ON station_id = start_station_id
ORDER BY number_of_rides DESC
```

Comment: Code-only answers are poor. Explain how/why this answers the question. But this does not answer the question asked in the post. [answer] [Help] Please format code reasonably. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at citibike_trips 'start_station_id', it has the datatype INTEGER whereas citibike_stations 'station_id' is a STRING. Previewing the tables you can see that they do not look anything alike, so the CAST query cannot be used to solve the issue. I found a workaround by joining the 'name' and 'start_station_name' fields instead. Query below:

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  name,
  number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station
FROM
  (SELECT
      start_station_id,
    start_station_name,
      COUNT(*) AS number_of_rides
  FROM
      `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
    GROUP BY
        start_station_id, start_station_name) AS station_num_trips
  INNER JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` ON name = start_station_name
ORDER BY
  number_of_rides DESC
```

Comment: While it looks like your query works, your query and explanation do not address the aliasing issue in the question that was asked.